# Domino Designer : Eclipse Project Loses External Jar References

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, designer, lotus-domino

I'me developping a java agent with Designer 8.5 with external jars in the project. 
It works fine except when I close and reopen the project.
Then something quite strange happens: in the project build properties the references to jars are present but not taken in account, so there are compilation errors. 
Then if I save a source file and come back to the project properties the references have gone. 
So I must use the button "Add external jars" to redeclare them.

Has someone had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Mikkel Heisterberg has a great summary of the options available to you in regards to [Managing external Java dependencies in Domino Designer](http://lekkimworld.com/2006/03/26/managing_external_java_dependencies_in_domino_designer.html)

Basically, it boils down to:

1. Include the classes in the agent/web service you are writing
2. Put the classes in a Java script library and include the script library
3. Use the JavaUserClasses notes.ini setting
4. Put the classes in the jvm/lib/ext folder

Was that the information you were looking for? If not, please describe where/how you are using the external jars (Agents, Xpages, Managed Bean, ...).

Comment: No, the problem seems to come from designer itself (that is Eclipse embedded in it)